# Django Oscar, how to make product price dynamic, by allowing users to enter their own value

Tags: django, django-oscar

Im using django-oscar as my e-commerce library,

What I want to do is to give users an input field they can use to enter the amount they want to pay for a product

When a user presses the add to cart, button they are presented with a Price Input Field

How can I archieve this?

Comment: why would you implement such a disastrous functionality of oscar framework?

Comment: what would you suggest I implement this functionality, it is available in many Ecommerse sites, whereby they just provide the user with a slider to determine their pricing